# Map an array of N 2D coordinates into an array of N 2D grids/images

Tags: python, numpy

My input is a set of N 2D coordinates in the form of a numpy array, e.g.:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.array([
  [-5, 1],
  [3, 7.2],
  [0, -7],
  [9, -8],
  [0, 0.1]
])
```

Here N would be 5 coordinates.

We can bin each point to some `resolution` X `resultion` 2D grid parameter on the 2D field for which we know the `min_X` and `max_X` for both dimensions:

```py
resultion = 100
min_X = -10
max_X = 10
bins = np.linspace(min_X, max_X, resolution + 1)
X_binned = np.digitize(X, bins) - 1
X_binned
```

> ```
> array([[25, 55],
>       [65, 86],
>       [50, 15],
>       [95, 10],
>       [50, 50]], dtype=int64)
> ```

So for example here we have a 100 X 100 grid on the [-10,10] X [-10,10] field, and point (-5, 1) maps to cell (25,55).

Now I would like a set of 2D all-zero grids, in the form of a `N X resolution X resolution X 1` numpy array (or a set of "images"). For each grid i there should appear 1 for coordinate i location.

This is what I'm doing but it seems not very numpy-y and the complexity is O(N) (N would eventually be around 100K):

```py
X_images = np.zeros((X.shape[0], resolution, resolution, 1), dtype=np.uint8)
for i, (j, k) in enumerate(X_binned):
    X_images[i, resolution - 1 - k, j, 0] = 1
```

To show that it works see e.g. first point (-5, 1) which maps to where it should be on the `X_images[0]` grid/image:

```py
plt.imshow(X_images[0])
plt.show()
```

[image]

So is there a better way, if not more efficient more elegant?

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning behind the extra dimension? I'm not understanding why a "set of 2D all-zero grids where one coordinate in each should be 1" means a 4D array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set them all at once by indexing `X_images` with the list of rows and cols:

```
X_images = np.zeros((X.shape[0], resolution, resolution, 1), dtype=np.uint8)

i = np.arange(X.shape[0])
j = X_binned[:, 0]
k = resolution - 1 - X_binned[:, 1]

X_images[i, k, j] = 1
```

Comment: Wow. Gotta love numpy.

Answer (score 1):

Using `np.ix_()` makes this pretty straight forward:

```py
X_images = np.zeros((X_binned.shape[0], 100, 100, 1), dtype="uint8")
X_images[np.ix_(np.arange(N), *X_binned.T, [0])] = 1
```

Comment: The reason behind the 4th dimension is that downstream those images would enter a convolutional neural network. Thanks!